# Crystal Report NullReferenceException when called with QueryString input parameters

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Report which I am calling through an .aspx page. My Crystal Report needs to accept Date and Percentage from the front end. When I run this report from the front end without passing any parameters, it runs fine.

To input the report parameters, I use QueryString values which map to Crystal parameters. Crystal needs to pick those parameters from there.

I receive the following error when I pass the QueryString values:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

This seems strange because the URL seems to be fine.  What could be causing the exception?

Comment: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` means you have a nullpointer exception

Comment: Can you post the code that passes the query string parameters to Crystal?  Do you have a more detailed stack trace for the exception?  Have you looked at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255212/how-to-pass-parameters-to-crystal-report ?  Also, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Procedure Written in the SQL Devolper has the input parameter as @percent
and crystal was also showing the input parameter as @percent. But the attribute coming in the URL from visula studio was percent only.

HEnce this objection was there. Renamed the parameter of crystal to percent and this report works smooth now.
Thanks all you tried to help me out.